# Cannot access shortcuts stored in dictionary for pygame key presses

Tags: python, dictionary, pygame, shortcut

```py
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *


class Text:

    def __init__(self, text, pos, **options) -> None:
        self.text = text
        self.pos = pos

        self.fontname = None
        self.fontsize = 72
        self.fontcolor = Color("black")
        self.set_font()
        self.render()

    def set_font(self):
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(self.fontname, self.fontsize)

    def render(self):
        self.img = self.font.render(self.text, True, self.fontcolor)
        self.rect = self.img.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = self.pos

    def draw(self):
        App.screen.blit(self.img, self.rect)


class App:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pygame.init()
        flags = RESIZABLE
        App.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 240), flags)
        App.t = Text("Pygame App", pos=(50, 50))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Object Oriented Programming")

    def do_shortcut(self, event):
        self.shortcut = {}
        k = event.key
        m = event.mod
        if (k, m) in self.shortcut:
            exec(self.shortcut[k, m])

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    self.do_shortcut(event)

            App.screen.fill(Color("gray"))
            App.t.draw()
            pygame.display.update()
        pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = App()
    app.run()
```

This is the whole programme above. I tried to store all the key combinations in a dictionary, access them and execute.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was that you initialized the shortcut every time when you entered the `do_shortcut` function:

`def do_shortcut(self, event): self.shortcut = {}`

you should initialize and put the self.shortcut = {} at the `__init__` function with some real values.

here is a working code:

```
import sys
import time
import pygame
from pygame import QUIT, KEYDOWN
RESIZABLE = True


class Text:
    def __init__(self, text, pos, **options) -> None:
        self.text = text
        self.pos = pos
        self.fontname = None
        self.fontsize = 72
        self.fontcolor = pygame.Color("black")
        self.set_font()
        self.render()

    def set_font(self):
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(self.fontname, self.fontsize)

    def render(self):
        self.img = self.font.render(self.text, True, self.fontcolor)
        self.rect = self.img.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = self.pos

    def draw(self):
        App.screen.blit(self.img, self.rect)


class App:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.shortcut = {(1073741906, 4096): 'down', (1073741905, 4096): 'up'}
        pygame.init()
        flags = RESIZABLE
        App.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 240), flags)
        App.t = Text("Pygame App", pos=(50, 50))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Object Oriented Programming")

    def do_shortcut(self, event):
        print("doing")
        k = event.key
        m = event.mod
        print("k = {}, m = {}".format(k, m))
        if (k, m) in self.shortcut:
            print("executing: {}".format(self.shortcut[k, m]))
            exec(self.shortcut[k, m])

    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                print(event)
                print(event.type)
                print(KEYDOWN)
                print("-" * 50)
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    print("*" * 100)
                    self.do_shortcut(event)

            App.screen.fill(pygame.Color("gray"))
            App.t.draw()
            pygame.display.update()
        pygame.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.run()
```

of course it will fail once it will reach the result of your shortcut which is 'up' and 'down' that I wrote just for testing, it can't exec that.

but if you will fill the shortcut in the right place in the `__init__` functon it will work.

Let me know if you need some help with something else.